# VBA can't find C# dll entry point

Tags: c#, vba, dll, com-interop

I'm creating a dll in C# which runs a simulation when a single function runSimulation() is called. This dll should be called from VBA, as certain parameter values are given as input in Excel. This is the code I use.

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace Simulation
{
    public static class Simulation
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [DllExport("runSimulation", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
        public static int runSimulation()
        {
            // Do simulation

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is compiled as a Class Library with x64 as Platform Target and returns Simulation.dll.

VBA:

```
Public Declare Function runSimulation Lib "Simulation.dll" () As Long

Sub Run_DLL()
ChDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path)
Dim returnValue As Long
returnValue = runSimulation()
End Sub
```

Running the Visual Basic code returns

> run-time error 453: 'Can't find DLL entry point runSimulation in
>   Simulation.dll'

when it tries to call runSimulation().

As a reference: I've tried running with

```
[DllExport("runSimulation", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

instead, but this also doesn't work. I additionally tried using the advice given in https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/40949-258782989 but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to compile it as x86 because you are calling it from a VBA system (which I think is 32-bit by default)?

Comment: Did you create a *.tlb file?

Comment: If you're exporting it at a C-style function and not a COM function then you should take off the `[ComVisible]` attribute.  It probably isn;t hurting anything (since static methods aren't usable by COM anyways) but it looks confusing.

Comment: @RubberDuck that would be for a COM library, not a native DLL.

Comment: Oh. My mis-understanding @DStanley. I've always done this kind of access from vba via COM interop. Marijn, if that tag I added isn't appropriate, you might want to remove it.

Comment: The class *is* a COM class and COM Interop should work. The OP is trying to call it though as if it were a C-style function. Unless the OP is using a 64-bit Office application though, it isn't possible to use a 64-bit DLL.

Comment: @RonBeyer Compiling it as an x86 dll returns the same error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos COM does not support static methods, so the method cannot be used in COM-Interop.  I don't know if the _class_ will be COM visible but at best it would have no com-visible methods.

Comment: Based on other examples of using Giesecke.DllExport (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/791891/Csharp-unmanaged-DLL-Export-Import-in-Cplusplus) I'm fairly sure that dll is correctly created and that the problem lies in how the function is called from VBA. My experience of VBA is limited though. Did I call the dll correctly from VBA?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Changing the method runSimulation and the Simulation class to non-static results in the error 'Only static methods can be exported'. Every other example I've found of DllExport also exports only static methods. Is there a way to create the dll correctly that does not require DllExport?

Comment: @Marijn you are mixing up different calling methods. Either use COM or C-style calls, not both. It's always tricky to use C-style calls in VBA so COM is preferable. MSDN has How To guides that show both how to [expose code to VBA from C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608604.aspx) *and* [how to call the exposed code from VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608613.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to call the 'runSimulation' function in VBA code, by exposing the Simulation class through an interface in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NSSimulation
{
    public interface ISimulation
    {
        int runSimulation();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Simulation : ISimulation
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public int runSimulation()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then re-compile your project and export your rebuilt library with 'tlbexp.exe' from the Visual Studio command prompt:

```
tlbexp.exe SimulationLib.dll /out:"SimulationLib.tlb" /win64
```

Then open the Visual Basic editor in Excel and add a reference to 'SimulationLib.tlb' through "Tools->References->Browse". To verify

```
Public x As New SimulationLib.Simulation

Sub test()
   MsgBox x.runSimulation
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a `Class not registered` error which I'm guessing is because `regasm` wasn't ran on the assembly itself  and `Register for COM interop` wasn't selected in VS.